# .htaccess rewrite just works with some pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess acts very strange. The following works perfectly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^band/biografie/?$ /band-biografie.php?page=3 [R,NC,L]
```

... but this does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^termine/?$ /termine.php?page=3 [R,NC,L]
```

It loads termine.php correctly, but does not do the redirect [R] and does not load page 3.
Both files (band-biografie.php and termine.php) are located in the same folder and basically have the same content.

Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...are you sure the page you are trying to redirect does not need more params (id) i.e.: /termine.php?page=3&id=649 ?

Comment: yes, both pages just react to page= for pagination :/

Comment: The dir is the same name without extension on the 2nd rule. change the top line to this `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and see if that helps

Comment: I usually redirect with full URL as the destination param instead of creating a new rewrite rules for each. So in your case it would use Redirect 301 /termine/ http://www.yoursite.com//termine.php?page=3 then you can have 100s of redirect lines for each URL (may affect your site's performance if you have 1000's of rules since the Apache has to call it each time it receives new request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -MultiViews did it for me:

> The dir is the same name without extension on the 2nd rule. change the top line to this Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews and see if that helps

Thank you both for your answers!